# mypy: Signature of "__getitem__" incompatible with supertype "Sequence"

Tags: python, typing, typechecking, mypy

I have a class that inherits from `MutableSequence` like this:

```
class QqTag(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self):
        self._children = []
    def __getitem__(self, idx: int) -> 'QqTag':
        return self._children[idx]
```

*mypy* complains that `Signature of "__getitem__" incompatible with supertype "Sequence"`.

In `Sequence`, this method is defined as:

```
@abstractmethod
def __getitem__(self, index):
    raise IndexError
```

So, what's the problem and why *mypy* isn't happy with my implementation?

Comment: Just a guess - but what happens if you remove the type annotation...?

Comment: @JonClements: this should be possible to specify, however.

Comment: @Martijn yeah... was just a wild guess that if it's checking the type annotation and moaning that it thinks it's being restrictive from the base - after all, the `idx` needn't be an `int` etc...

Comment: Relevant [typing issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/241), summarising the [mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1237).

Comment: If I replace `idx: int` with simple `idx`, it doesn't complain. Possible a bug in `collections`? I believe `Sequence`s should be indexed with `int`s anyway.

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov not necessarily - a `slice` is also valid (although technically - anything is valid depending on what you want to do with it - but with things that are going to emulate `list` like behaviour then it's normally `int`s or `slice`s)

Comment: @JonClements, okay, I agree about slices. Anyway, are there any way to make mypy happy and keep `idx: int` restriction?

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov look at the issues that Martijn has pointed out :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, I read this and understood the actual problem with my code. However, I'm still cannot understand how to do it properly. I'll probably have to ask another question for that…

Comment: @MartijnPieters could you please look at my [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690012/subclassing-sequence-with-proper-type-hints-in-python)?

Comment: @IlyaV.Schurov: isn't that essentially the same question? Sorry, I do not currently have an answer.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in comments, a typeof slice can also be passed.  Ie, change `idx: int` to `idx: Union[int, slice]`.

This will make mypy happy (at least on my machine ;):

```
class QqTag(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self):
        self._children = []

    def __getitem__(self, idx: Union[int, slice]) -> 'QqTag':
        return self._children[idx]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the [typing.overload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) decorator.

```
from typing import overload

class QqTag(MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self):
        self._children = []
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> 'QqTag':
        ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, s: slice) -> list['QqTag']:
        ...
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self._children[idx]
```

See examples from [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) or [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#function-method-overloading).