# How to correctly asses the typing of an index when writing type hints?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am writing a custom `Dataset` class for a particular deep learning problem and the question of how to annotate the `index` of `__getitem__` using type hints arose.

Given

```
    def __getitem__(self, i: int) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]: 
        return self.X[i], self.y[i]
```

what would be the best way to annotate `i` given the fact that it can be a slice (eg. `X[:i]`)?

Comment: Actually, `i` is a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object, not a "range"

Comment: I wasn't pedantic. Ty for the heads-up, I edited my q.

Comment: Related: [Subclassing Sequence with proper type hints in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46690012/7851470)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as I said, `i` can be and integer or a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) object.

So you can try:

```py
def __getitem__(self, i: Union[int, slice]) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

That'd be a [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) of types:

```
from typing import Union, Tuple

def __getitem__(self, i: Union[int, slice]) -> Tuple[Tensor, Tensor]:
    . . .
```

`Union[int, slice]` means "it can be a `int`, or it can be a `slice`".